# Android event when switching to an activity from a tab, not sure how OnTabChangeListener would work

Tags: android, android-tabhost

this is a rough idea of what my program looks like

MainTabHost Activity (startup)

===>  Tab1  (activity1.java)

```
         public void refresh();
```

===>  Tab2  (activity2.java)

I have a refresh function on activity1 that repaints a listview.  If I switch to Tab2, then switch back to Tab1, I need an event to call that function.

All the examples for OnTabChangeListener involve defining the event at the startup activity.. however at that level, I'm not sure how to invoke a function in activity1/2 ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used `TabActivity` but I would assume that `onResume()` gets called when you switch to a new activity as per the android activity lifecycle. Could you do your `refresh()` in the `onResume()` of your tab1 activity?